# Equivalent to Roth's theorem

Tags: number-theory, inequality, diophantine-approximation

> Let $\alpha$ be a real algebraic number of degree $\geq 3$. Prove that the following three assertions are equivalent:
>
> 1. for every $\kappa >2$ there is a constant $c(\alpha,\kappa)>0$ such that
>      $$|\xi-\alpha| \geq c(\alpha,\kappa) H(\xi)^{-\kappa}$$ 
>      for every $\xi \in \mathbb{Q}$.
> 2. for every $\kappa >2$, the inequality
>      $$|\xi -\alpha| \leq H(\xi)^{-\kappa}$$ 
>      in $\xi \in \mathbb{Q}$ has only finitely many solutions

I have managed $(1) \Rightarrow (2)$: 
Choose $\kappa'$ such that $\kappa > \kappa' > 0$

$$H(\xi)^{-\kappa} \geq |\xi -\alpha| \geq c(\alpha,\kappa')H(\xi)^{-\kappa'}$$
Implies $\dfrac{1}{c(\alpha,\kappa')} \geq H(\xi)^{\kappa-\kappa'}$. Hence $H(\xi)$ is bounded, so there are finitely many $\xi$.

From $(2)$ we have there are infinitely many $\xi$ with $ |\xi -\alpha| \geq H(\xi)^{-\kappa}$ however I can't indicate $c(\alpha,\kappa)$ such that for all $\xi$ this inequality holds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\xi_1, \ldots, \xi_\ell$ denote the finitely many solutions to the inequality in $(2)$. Note that since $\alpha$ has degree at least $3$, $\alpha \neq 0$ and thus $\xi_i \neq 0$ for any of the finite number of solutions to the inequality.

Define the constant $c$ by
$$ c = \inf_{1 \leq i \leq \ell} \Big(\lvert \xi_i - \alpha \rvert H(\xi_i)^\kappa\Big).$$
As there are only finitely many terms, this $c$ is well-defined and $c > 0$. Further, we can assume $c < 1$, as otherwise there would be no exceptional $\xi_i$.

Then we necessarily have that $\lvert \xi_i - \alpha\rvert \geq c H(\xi_i)^{-\kappa}$ for each exceptional $\xi_i$. For nonexceptional $\xi_i$, the stronger inequality $\lvert \xi - \alpha\rvert \geq H(\xi)^{-\kappa} \geq c H(\xi)^{-\kappa}$ holds. Thus the inequality in $(1)$ holds for all $\xi$.